# insert data form to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

somebody tell me where's the mistake please

html code is :

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<label>Firstname:</label> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="first name" /><br />
<label>Lastname:</label> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="last name" /><br />
<label>email:</label> <input type="text" name ="email" value="email" /><br />
```

php code is :

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])!='')
    {
    $fname=$_POST ['firstname'];
    $lname=$_POST ['lastname'];
    $email=$_POST ['email'];
    mysql_connect ("localhost","root","mydatabase") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db ("my_db") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_query ("ISERT INTO userinfo (`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email')");
    echo "successfully updated" ;
    }
```

?>

Comment: DONE mistake in "INSERT"

Comment: The code is a ripe target for SQL Injection, I recommend reading this ASAP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `INSERT` not `ISERT`.. You have a typo there

```
mysql_query ("ISERT INTO userinfo (`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`)
              ^^^^^
```

#### Modified Code..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['firstname'],$_POST ['lastname'],$_POST ['email']))
{
    $fname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    mysql_connect ("localhost","root","mydatabase") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db ("my_db") or die (mysql_error ());
    $result=mysql_query ("INSERT INTO userinfo (`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email')");
    if($result){     echo "Successfully Updated" ; } else {die(mysql_error());}
}
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: could you please tell me how to switch to preparedstatements 
and should i edit in html code too to switch to preparedstatements ?

Comment: Nope you don't have to edit in the HTML. Here's the link how you use Prepared Statements. If you have any questions come, back. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($_POST) {
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    mysql_connect ("localhost","root","mydatabase") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db ("my_db") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO userinfo (firstname,lastname,email)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email')");
    echo "successfully updated" ;
}
```

In your example I don't see `$_POST['submit']` and you have mistake with `INSERT`